# Ajuda para enviar dados por metodo post em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Estou fazendo um checker para estudos, tenho uma api de login, mas fico dando de cara com esse erro:

```
<Response [403]>
```

Tentei tambem fazer request post pelo postman e deu o seguinte erro:

```
{
"sucesso": false,
"msg": "400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."
}
```

Com as seguintes configuracoes no postman:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import requests
import json

post_context_data = {
    "email": "teste@gmail.com",
    "senha": "21312321321",
    "session": {},
}

headers_context_data = {
    "User-Agente": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36',
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
}
api_sender = requests.session()
json_content = api_sender.post("https://servicespub.prod.api.aws.**********.com.br/login/v1/usuario/login", data=json.dumps(post_context_data), headers=headers_context_data)
print(json_content)
```

O "session" ele gera no cookie: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu não sei como eu pego um cookie especifico do site?

No BurpSuite eu consigo fazer a resposta vir, segue alguns prints de login invalido e valido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -3):

O 403 - Forbidden é um erro que dá quando algo está errado no request, geralmente. Por exemplo: quando um site detecta que o que você está enviando para ele pode ser perigoso para o site ele retorna 403, como se ele ignorasse por ser inseguro. Isso pode ser algum autenticador do site. Não é um erro no código, e sim no que você está enviando.